# KeenTools FaceBuilder for Blender Mac

Tags: blend-files

I am having trouble installing KeenTools FaceBuilder Beta for Blender on my Mac.
I am curious if anyone has been successful installing the Mac version yet?
I have installed the windows version without any issue at all and it works great.

https://keentools.io/download/facebuilder-for-blender

https://keentools.io/download/core

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: I work on Mac and this installs perfect with 2.81. Since you installed this also on a Windows-machine i assume you used the correct method of installing.

Answer (score 1):

I think Blender needs either a *.py or *.zip file for add-ons. I downloaded the *.dmg, decompressed it and then I zipped it. Then i was able to install the add-on.